# Limiting the number of ListViewBuilder item in a row

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

How can limit the number of Listviewbuilder items in a row ( for example I want to show 5 items in a row)and then goes to the next row .My code . There are more than 500 item in the list but I want just show 5 item in every line and then goes to the next line. Thank you

```
Container(
          height: 215.0,
          child: ListView.builder(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
              vertical: 12.0,
              horizontal: 8.0,
            ),
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemCount: contentList.length,
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              final Content content = contentList[index];
              return GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BookingCard()),
                  );
                },
                child: Stack(
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0),
                      height: 300.0,
                      width: 300.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        image: DecorationImage(
                          image: AssetImage(content.imageUrl),
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        border: Border.all(color: content.color, width: 3.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 300.0,
                      width: 300.0,
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: const LinearGradient(
                          colors: [
                            Colors.black87,
                            Colors.black45,
                            Colors.transparent,
                          ],
                          stops: [0, 0.25, 1],
                          begin: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          end: Alignment.topCenter,
                        ),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        border: Border.all(color: content.color, width: 3.0),
                      ),
                    ),
                    // Positioned(
                    //   left: 0,
                    //   right: 0,
                    //   bottom: 0,
                    //   child: SizedBox(
                    //     height: 60.0,
                    //     child: Image.asset(content.titleImageUrl),
                    //   ),
                    // ),
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ListView` widget is for the purposes of laying out items in a single direction and allow scrolling on them in the same direction.

If you want your items to be wrapped into the next line when there is not space, there are two options for you.

1. Use a `GridView`

   As the name says, `GridView` lays down it's items horizontally and depending upong the  configuration you give to the `GridView` automatically goes to the next line.
2. Use a `Wrap`

   `Wrap` simply wrap your horizontally laid down widgets whenever there is no space left to put the next element, moving it to the next line.

Considering, you item count and specific need to display 5 items only,

you would need to use `GridView.builder` along with `SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount` to achieve this.

Replace your `ListView.builder` with

```
GridView.builder(
  gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(crossAxisCount: 5),
  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    // Rest of the code is the same
  },
)
```

Comment: Thank you Nisanth for always being helpful. You r right, better to use Gridview but because my list is Dynamic. I used GridView.Builder instead of Count. 

Btw. I really appreciate it you can check our room. I still have the problem with that code. And sent all the screenshots overthere

Comment: Can you ping the room url once. I can't seem to find it.